# React Player subtitles are not showing

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, react-player

I receive my subtitles dynamically from the remote API but I can't get them to show in my `react-player`

```
      <ReactPlayer
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        url={src}
        controls={true}
        config={{
          file: {
            tracks: [
              {
                kind: 'subtitles',
                src: 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/'path'/subtitles-test.vtt',
                srcLang: 'en',
                default: true,
                label: 'eng',
              },
            ],
          },
        }}
      />
```

I also tried adding `crossOrigin: 'true'` to the `attributes` property but that makes me unable to play the video (it just gets stuck at 00:00)

Adding subtitles locally works just fine

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken we had to change some CORS settings on the backend to make it work. Here is what the config looks like right now and the subtitles are working 
config={{
            file: {
              attributes: {
                crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
              },
              tracks: [
                {
                  kind: 'subtitles',
                  src: subtitles ,
                  srcLang: 'en',
                  default: false,
                  label: 'eng',
                },
              ],
            },
          }}

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to access the .vtt file from an aws S3 bucket. When adding `crossOrigin: 'true'` to the `attributes` property, make sure that you update the CORS configuration on your S3 bucket to explicitly allow requests from the domain, from where you are trying to access this file (for example: 'http://localhost:3000").

Here's an example CORS configuration:

```
[
  {
    "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
    "AllowedMethods": ["GET"],
    "AllowedOrigins": ["http://localhost:3000"],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
  }
]
```

It is **important** that you **update the CORS configuration for all the S3 buckets, that your ReactPlayer component tries to access**. So for example, if you have one bucket for hosting the video and another bucket for hosting the subtitle files, both need to have the CORS configurations updated accordingly.